# Plotting ParametricNDSolve Value

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, parametric-functions

I am trying to solve a set of coupled differential equations, where I would create plots for a(t) and e(t), where the parameter RAST can be varied. However, every time I try to plot, I get blank plots.
How would I go about doing this?

To emphasise, I am looking to generate 2 separate plots; one for a(t) and one for e(t), which each contain multiple, different coloured graphs showing the variation of the parameter, RAST.

My code:

````
In[3]:=
LSUN = 3.83*10^26; 
MSUN = 1.989*10^30; 
MWD = MSUN; 
year = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[
     Quantity[1, "Years"], "Seconds"]]; 
km = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[
     Quantity[1, "Kilometers"], 
     "Meters"]]; timelimit = 
   year*2*10^9; Myr = 1*10^6*year; 

In[10]:=
PROPCONST = 1.27; 

In[7]:=
c = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[
     Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], 
     "Meters/second"]]; \[Rho] = 2000; 
MAST[rast_] := (4/3)*Pi*rast^3*\[Rho]; 
RSUN = 696340000; 
AU = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[
     Quantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit"], 
     "meters"]]; 

In[9]:=
L[t_] := (3.26*LSUN*(MWD/(0.6*MSUN)))/
    (0.1 + t/Myr)^1.18; 

In[10]:=
dadt = (-(1/c^2))*((RAST^2*L[t]*
      (2 + 3*e[t]^2))/(4*MAST[RAST]*a[t]*
      (1 - e[t]^2)^(3/2))); 
dedt = (-(5/c^2))*((RAST^2*L[t]*e[t])/
     (8*MAST[RAST]*a[t]^2*
      Sqrt[1 - e[t]^2])); 

In[16]:=
prsol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
   {Derivative[1][a][t] == dadt, 
    Derivative[1][e][t] == dedt, 
    a[0] == 2*AU, e[0] == 0.5}, {a, e}, 
   {t, 0, timelimit}, {RAST}]

Out[16]= ParametricFunction[ <> ]

In[18]:=
asol[RAST_, t_] := prsol[RAST][[1]][t]; 
esol[RAST_, t_] := prsol[RAST][[2]][t]; 
```
````

Comment: tried `Plot[Evaluate[Table[prsol[ r][[1]][t], {r, 1, 10}]], {t, 0, 
  timelimit}]` and `Plot[Evaluate[Table[prsol[ r][[2]][t], {r, 1, 10}]], {t, 0, 
  timelimit}]`?

Comment: Brilliant. I think that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Row[{Plot[Evaluate[Table[prsol[r][[1]][t], {r, 1, 10}]], {t, 0, timelimit}, 
    ImageSize -> Medium], 
  Plot[Evaluate[Table[prsol[r][[2]][t], {r, 1, 10}]], {t, 0, timelimit}, 
    ImageSize -> Medium]}]
```

[image]

Using `{t, 0, timelimit / 10^4}` gives

[image]